# Lua - tcp connection print contents of site

Tags: sockets, lua

I use:

```
host = "www.w3.org"
file = "/TR/REC-html32.html"
c = assert(socket.connect(host, 80))
c:send("GET " .. file .. " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
contents = c:receive("*a")
print(contents)
```

To print the contents of the site `www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html`. However, later on I want to print the contents of the site again, that may have changed from the previous time but if I use `contents = c:receive("*a")` again, `nil` is printed and I have to use the above example for the new contents to be printed again. How can I print the new contents without having to do another tcp connection to the site, I mean stay connected and print the contents of time (every 60 seconds let's say)?

Comment: You'd need to resend the `GET` request. Think of it as pressing the refresh button of your browser!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the TCP socket, it's easier to use the [HTTP module](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html):

```
local http = require("socket.http")

while(true) do
  b, c, h = http.request("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html")
  print(b)
  --sleep(60)
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I really need to use TCP socket tho =/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to recreate the tcp object; but you DO NEED to resend the `GET` request to the server.

Therefore, you'll need to execute the following two statements in your timer/loop:

```
c:send( "GET "..file.." HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" )
contents = c:receive "*a"
```

where `c` is the same as created in your code.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried it before and gave nil value... Will retest and tell you. Thanks

Comment: `c:receive "*a"` read data until socket not closed. So I think you need recreate socket each time. I do not remember that LuaSocket using to reconnection.

Comment: @moteus I tried the above as follows: http://codepad.org/61TZwdEY and it was working